# Attempting to remove pointers in a list causes constant memory usage growth

Tags: c++, list, memory, pointers, memory-leaks

I think I'm attempting the wrong approach here so please tell me if what I'm trying to achieve won't work with this "technique".

I have an object callled Spawner which spawns KillerObjects every X ms, when I want the KillerObject to be destroyed I call:

```
void Spawner::RemoveKillerObject(KillerObject* removeThis)
{
    garbageList.push_back(removeThis);
}
```

Then everytime the Spawner is updated it will loop through the garbageList to remove every object that has been pushed into the garbage list, like this:

```
 void Spawner::Update(float elapsedTime)
 {
     elapsedSince += elapsedTime;
     if (elapsedSince > spawnRate)
     {
        Spawn();
        elapsedSince = 0;
     }
     for each (KillerObject* removeThis in garbageList)
     {
         spawnedObjects.remove(removeThis);
     }
     garbageList.clear();

     for each (KillerObject* ko in spawnedObjects)
     {
            ko->Update(elapsedTime);
     }
 }
```

Spawn is simply creating a pointer to a KillerObject and pushes it into the spawnedObject list.

The objects are "deleted" in the game as in I can't collide with them and they won't be drawn.
But this causes my memory usage to continuously grow, I know this is the cause because if I remove this code the memory usage is stable.

A point in the right direction or any other help is very much appreciated.

Kind regards

Markus

Comment: what's the type of `garbageList`

Comment: Both garbageList and spawnedObjects are list<KillerObject*>

Comment: Is `spawnedObjects.remove(removeThis);` actually deleting the object or is it just removing the pointer from another container? - Judging by the fact you have a leak I'd guess the latter in which case you need to delete the object too.

Comment: Yes, but how would I achieve this since I can't delete something in a for each loop. Would using iterators work?

Comment: I have never seen such `for` loops in C++ ... what is this?

Comment: I've been coding a lot in C# before C++ and in C# for each loops are common, apparently they work in C++ as well.

Comment: @fmaas it's new syntax -- C++11, check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop#C.2B.2B) out

Comment: actually, I just noticed the syntax isn't quite the same, so.. not sure what these are actually :-D

Comment: I can't find any information regarding for each in C++, I just tried and apparently it worked =)
They are very comfortable but will not work for occasions like this when I want to remove something from the list, in this case I had to use iterators for the actual deletion.
Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: How are you determining memory usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit, that I have not completely understood your code, but you probably have a memory leak, i.e. produce more objects `new KillerObject()` than you `delete`. You could use a similar statement somewhere to remove the objects that are no longer needed:

```
for (std::list<KillerObject*>::iterator it = garbageList.begin(); it != garbageList.end(); ++it) {
  delete (*it);
}
garbageList.clear();
```

or just change:

```
void Spawner::RemoveKillerObject(KillerObject* removeThis)
{
  delete removeThis;
  //garbageList.push_back(removeThis);
  // todo: add code to remove the pointer from the list
  removeThis = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Careful, the second option deletes the object but doesn't remove the pointer from the list -- when the list is looped over later there'll be tears.

Comment: In my case the second one would not work since RemoveKillerObject() is called from within a for each loop.
I guess I'm lazy but I find for each loops very comfortable and they work perfectly in all occasions except when I want to remove something.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: if you use C++11, this is a good use case for the `auto` keyword :)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you're not actually deleting the objects? You're removing them from the list, but I can't see a delete statement anywhere...?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that could be the problem, that's why I think my approach might not work, since you can't delete something in a for each loop...

Comment: I don't really use the foreach loop, so I'm not sure about that. I can't see why you couldn't just do this with a normal for loop though -- you'd be able to delete the objects then.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the pointer won't cause the object it's pointing to to be deleted. Here are some options to consider:

1) Store smart pointers instead of standard pointers

2) Delete the object before you remove it from `spawnedObjects`

3) Make `spawnedObjects` of type `list<KillerObject>` instead so that the `remove` call *does* delete it!